# What `if char =~# '\w'` means in Vimscript?

Tags: vim

What does `if char =~# '\w'` means in vim script? And what's `\w`, `\W`, `\k`?

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` checks if the char matches word character. The `#` in `=~#` can be skipped.

```
:h \w
:h \W
:h \k
:h =~
```

First of all, learn to use `:h`

Comment: Well, the `#` in `=~#` can be skipped *in this case*, but in general it means the operator will be case-sensitive regardless of the `'ignorecase'` setting. I think that's an important part of the answer, since the `#` and `?` modifiers are fairly unique to Vimscript and are often what people might find very foreign coming from other languages. (But, yeah, learn to use `:h` is the main point here!)

Comment: @filbranden yes, ur right. I meant the `#` can be sipped **in this if statement**. `#` does a case-sensitive comparison, but the `\w` contains both lower and upper cases.

Answer (score 1):

The `=~` operator performs a pattern match of the right operand on the left operand.

The `\w` means any word character (a-z|A-Z|0-9). You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp).

The `\W` means anything but a word character.